# Receiving a 404 error even though page exists while trying to POST with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, python, django, http, angularjs

`POST http://api.link/api/v1/articlerevision 404 (NOT FOUND)`

I get the following error when I try to add a new item through AngularJS and Django-Tastypie API. If I open the link in browser, it works, bet when I submit the form, it doesn't. I have set `allowed_methods` to `get, put, post, delete` and that doesn't seem to solve anything. What other options could there be?

EDIT:

view.tpl.html

```
<div ng-controller="CreateCtrl">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <label>
            Title
            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="revision.title" placeholder="Title">
            </label>

            <br />

            <label>
            Description
            <textarea class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="revision.content"></textarea>
            </label>

            <button ng-click="create()">Save</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Angular

```
var tastypieDataTransformer = function ($http) {
    return $http.defaults.transformResponse.concat([
        function (data, headersGetter) {
            var result = data.objects;
            result.meta = data.meta;
            return result;
        }
    ]);
};

bosApp.factory('Revision', function($resource, $http) {
    return $resource('http://api.link/api/v1/articlerevision/:id/', {
            id: '@is'
        },
        {
            update: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {"update": true},
                isArray: false
            },
            save: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                transformResponse: tastypieDataTransformer($http)
            },
            create: {
                method: 'POST'
            }
        }
    );
});

var CreateCtrl = function($scope, $location, Revision) {
    $scope.create = function() {
        Revision.create($scope.revision);
    };
};
```

Comment: Show us the view and the angular code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EtpiNZQm here you go, if that's the one you're asking for

Comment: What does `@method_decorator(get_article(can_write=True, can_create=True))` do? Must `ArticleMixin` be at right?

Comment: does `'http://api.link/api/v1/articlerevision/` exist ? (without :id)

Comment: To be honest, it's from a plugin and I don't quite know what each line of code does, but without trying to make it as a single page app, everything works. And that api link exists without :id as well.